# Определить язык на сайте play.google.com Curl запросом

Tags: php, curl

При получении содержимого сайта play.google.com через Curl, контент постоянно приходит на английском языке. Кто сталкивался и решил эту проблему? Возможно user-agent другой указать или каким-то образом передать страну... Подставленные российских прокси не решает проблему, смена сервера на российский или украинский так же не решает проблему.

Comment: [Accept-Language](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8/Accept-Language) ?

Comment: @teran помог Ваш ответ. Сделал так и заработало: `curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Accept-Language: ru-RU, ru;q=0.9, en-US;q=0.8, en;q=0.7, fr;q=0.6']);`

Comment: @Владимир ну так вы добавьте развёрнутый ответ к своему вопросу и нажмите галочку